# How can I send articles to Firefox for Android's reading list from the desktop?

Tags: firefox, android, firefox-sync

I use Firefox on my desktop and Firefox for Android on my tablet, with Firefox Sync keeping them connected.  I'd like to use the Reading List feature of FF for Android, but often I find the articles I want to read while browsing on my desktop.

Is there a way that I can send a page or link on my desktop to the reading list so it will show up on the tablet? I'm happy to use an extension to accomplish this, if needed.

I'm currently using Pocket for this, but am wanting to explore Firefox's native functionality more.

Answer (score 5):

Currently there is no way to access stories saved in "reading list" from the desktop. The good news is that there is an open bug for this:

"Create a central reading list attached to fxa" https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1082011

In the interim you can use the "sync tabs" feature mentioned in the other answer. That being said I think it is a terrible workaround and will get unwieldy if you have more than a handful of stories to read later.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the extension [Send Tab To Device](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/send-tab-to-device/) which is going to be natively built into Firefox' code.

Concerning the Reader Mode, I'm not sure if it has been suggested already, so I think to suggest this additional feature, it's a good idea to add a comment to the related bug entry in Bugzilla [Bug 507471 - [meta] Send tabs to other browsers](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=507471).

Additional Reading: [Services/PushTabToDevice](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Services/PushTabToDevice)

Answer (score -1):

You can use Pushbullet to send links or tabs from the desktop to your other devices.

Comment: What is a pushbullet?  Please read http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers for guidance on how to recommend software in an answer.